# Spring Cloud Config Database Backend - Cannot resolve property

Tags: spring-boot, client-server, config, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

I have a requirement to store and consume configurations via PostgreSQL DB.I have entered following queries to the DB

```
CREATE TABLE xlabs.properties (
  application varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  profile varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  label varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  prop_key  varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  value varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
);

INSERT INTO xlabs.properties (application, profile, label, prop_key, value) VALUES ('config-server','development','latest','ssn','([0-9]{9})');
```

So, After running config server and hit on `http://localhost:8090/config-server/development/latest` will return this response.

```
{"name":"config-server","profiles":["development"],"label":"latest","version":null,"state":null,"propertySources":[{"name":"config-server-development","source":{"ssn":"([0-9]{9})"}}]}
```

But the problem is when I try to consume above ssn property through cloud config client with following configurations, in `bootstrap.properties`

```
spring.cloud.config.uri=http://localhost:8090
spring.profiles.active=development
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
spring.application.name=config-server
spring.cloud.config.label=latest
```

and

```
@RestController
@RefreshScope
public class ConfigController {
    @Value("${ssn}")
    private String name;

    @GetMapping("/message")
    public String returnConfig(){
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

So, When I run the project it gives run time error

**`Could not resolve placeholder 'ssn' in value "${ssn}"`**

Please help on this.

Answer (score 0):

After some hours of reading I was able to find out the answer.
This issue comes with very latest versions of Spring Boot. So their by default bootstrap properties are disabled. So you have to enable them by adding following dependency.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

For older versions this might not useful.
Thanks.